# Haskell: exception handling in non-IO monads

Tags: haskell, exception, monads, yesod

I started using Yesod to develop a little project, this is the first time I use Haskell to do something real.
This code that handles a registration form works fine:

```
postRegisterR :: Handler ()
postRegisterR = do email <- runInputPost $ ireq textField "email"
                   user  <- runInputPost $ ireq textField "user"
                   pwd   <- runInputPost $ ireq textField "pwd"
                   cpwd  <- runInputPost $ ireq textField "cpwd"
                   if pwd == cpwd && isValidEmail email
                      then do
                        tryInsert email user pwd
                        setSession "user" user
                        redirectUltDest SessionR
                      else do
                        redirect HomeR

tryInsert :: Text -> Text -> Text -> Handler ()
tryInsert email user pwd = do pwdbs <- liftIO $ hashedPwd pwd
                              _ <- runDB $ insert $ User email user pwdbs
                              return ()
```

Now the problem is: if I sign in twice with the same credentials I get an `InternalServerError`. This is right, because in my model configuration there is `UniqueUser email username`. So I'd like to catch and handle this error in some way. How can I do that and, in general, how exception handling works in Haskell when you are dealing with non-IO monads defined in an external library or framework?

PS: I read [this](http://mvanier.livejournal.com/5103.html) tutorial, but that is useful if you are designing a new library. I tryed to use the catch function, but I got a lot of type errors.

**Edit**

Thank you Ankur, your code worked with a little modification, to remove this error:

```
   Ambiguous type variable `e0' in the constraint:
      (Exception e0) arising from a use of `catch'
   Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

code:

```
tryInsert :: Text -> Text -> ByteString -> Handler Bool
tryInsert email user pwd = HandlerT (\d -> catch (unHandlerT (runDB $ insert $ User email user pwd) d 
                                                  >> return True)
                                                 (\(e :: SomeException) -> return False))
```

With `ScopedTypeVariables` extension enabled

**Edit 2**

Final version, after bennofs' hint:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Control.Exception.Lifted (catch)
import Control.Monad (void)

postRegisterR :: Handler ()
postRegisterR = do email <- runInputPost $ ireq textField "email"
                   user  <- runInputPost $ ireq textField "user"
                   pwd   <- runInputPost $ ireq textField "pwd"
                   cpwd  <- runInputPost $ ireq textField "cpwd"
                   if pwd == cpwd && isValidEmail email
                      then do
                        pwdbs <- liftIO $ hashedPwd pwd
                        success <- tryInsert email user pwdbs
                        case success of
                          True -> do setSession "user" user
                                     redirectUltDest SessionR
                          False -> redirect HomeR
                      else do
                        redirect HomeR

tryInsert :: Text -> Text -> ByteString -> Handler Bool
tryInsert email user pwd = do void $ runDB $ insert $ User email user pwd
                              return True
                              `catch` (\(e :: SomeException) ->
                                  do return False)
```

Comment: You could use [checkUnique](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/persistent/0.3.1.3/doc/html/Database-Persist.html#v:checkUnique) to test if the key is unique before you insert, and avoid the exception by handling that case differently.

Comment: Umh...there is no checkUnique in the newer versions of Yesod, but I found [insertUnique](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/persistent/latest/doc/html/Database-Persist-Class.html#v:insertUnique), thank you. Anyway I'm still interested in exception handling.

Comment: You can use `ScopedTypeVariables` language extension and then do `(\ (e :: SomeException) -> return False)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like shown below, basically `Handler` is `HandlerT` which is monad transformer (I haven't type checked the code below :))

```
tryInsert :: Text -> Text -> Text -> Handler Bool
tryInsert email user pwd = HandlerT (\d -> do pwdbs <- hashedPwd pwd
                                              catch (unHandlerT (runDB $ insert $ User email user pwdbs) d >> return True)
                                                    (\e -> return False))
```

And check the returned bool value if there was exception or not.

Answer (score 8):

There is a package called [lifted-base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lifted-base), which also provides a more generic catch function:

```
Control.Exception.Lifted.catch :: 
  (MonadBaseControl IO m, Exception e)
  => m a         -- ^ The computation to run
  -> (e -> m a)  -- ^ Handler to invoke if an exception is raised
  -> m a
```

There exists an instance MonadBaseControl IO Handler, so you can just use this function:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-} -- I think this is needed PatternSignatures.
import Control.Exception.Lifted (catch)
import Control.Monad (void)

tryInsert :: Text -> Text -> Text -> Handler ()
tryInsert email user pwd = do 
  pwdbs <- liftIO $ hashedPwd pwd
  (void $ runDB $ insert $ User email user pwdbs) `catch` \(e :: SomeException) -> do
    -- Your exception handling goes code here. This code also lives in the Handler monad.
    return ()
 return ()
```

Another possibility is to use [MonadCatchIO-mtl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadCatchIO-mtl), which also provides a generic catch function. MonadCatchIO-mtl won't build on GHC HEAD though. I also still think that using `insertUnique` is the cleanest way to handle this.

Comment: Thanks, this is also a good solution, you can avoid all that Handler/unHandler stuff. Yes the `insertUnique` way is probably the best solution in this case, but in general this discussion will be useful in future, I didn't found much clear information on the topic.